# Laravel Socialite(Google) Login Redirect To multiple Views

Tags: php, laravel

I have two views, Student and Teacher, I have implemented a Socialite login with specific domain of organization(student@abc.edu.pk) WHen the student login it redirect to **Home** Page/View. And now i create Teacher which also go through same login system, Teacher also have same domain name account teacher@abc.edu.pk , I want when teacher Login it should redirect to another View, (**TeacharHome**) How can i do that, I try my hard but could not do that...
Here

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Here My LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Socialite;
use Auth;
use App\User;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    protected $redirectTo1 = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {

        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

        $domain = explode("@", $user->email)[1];
        if( $domain != 'abc.edu.pk')
        {
            return redirect($this->redirectTo1);
        }
        else
        {
            $authUser=$this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
            Auth::login($authUser, true);
            return redirect($this->redirectTo);
            //return $user->token;
        }
    }

    public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
        if($authUser)
        {
            return $authUser;
        }
        return User::create([
            'name'=> $user->name,
            'email'=> $user->email,
            'provider'=> strtoupper($provider),
            'provider_id'=>$user->id
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any naming convention on the emails?

Comment: Domain Name For teacher and student is same, someone@abc.edu.pk but everyone have their own email, so after login they redirect to respective page

Comment: Then you need to distinguish them. You can use the callback URL and have different signup up buttons or you can ask what they before you redirect them. in any case, you need a way to identify them

Comment: The problem is how to distinguish between them...I donot know how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Try requesting upfront for the type. You can have a required radio button asking the type

```html
    <form method="post" action="auth/facebook">
      <label>
       Teacher
      <input type="radio" required value="teacher" name="type" />
      </label>
      <label>
      Student
      <input type="radio" required value="student" name="type" />
      </label><br>
      <button type="submit">Login with Facebook</button>  
    </form>
```

You can then include the type param on your callback and use it to redirect the user to the correct page

```php
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect(['type' => request()->input('type')]);
}
```

and finally, you redirect accordingly

```php
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
   //... Make sure you also use role and Role Base Access for security
   if (request()->query('type') === 'teacher') {
      return redirect()->route('home.teacher')
   }

   return redirect()->route('home.student')
}
```

hope it helps